# What is the ${$var.'s_array'} syntax in PHP?

Tags: php

I am currently debugging a PHP OpenCart plugin and I have came across syntax I have never came across before.

I am interested in what this does and why it's used, and links to any documentation. The culprit is below:

```
${$variable.'s_array'}
```

Comment: It's a "variable" variable and actually depends on the value of `$variable`. So let's say `$variable` is `"hello"`, it becomes `${'hellos_array'}` then `$hellos_array`.

Comment: PHP doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variables in PHP can have variables in their declaration, like this:

e.g. try running this code-snippet:

```
$var = "dog_name";
$$var = "golden terrier";
echo $dog_name; //gives "golden terrier"
```

now to your case:

```
$variable = "random_";
${$variable.'s_array'} = "somecontent";
echo $random_s_array; //gives "somecontent"
```

this will give you dynamic variables.

[**Try this Sandbox-Example :)**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/53fd9cd3887ad02ab09473f492b7febded69d158)

PHP-Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php (mentioned by versalle88)

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you so much :-)